# PHP - Warning: printf(): Too few arguments strange issue

Tags: php

I have a strange error

When i run the following code, once in a while i get

```
Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in /www/api/class.InvoicePayment.inc.php on line 92
```

However i don't understand why this happens because in my coding i have this line as

```
if($output!="")
      printf($output);
```

how can the this printf get a warning even when the output variable is not empty ..

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php Basically your output has some kind of placeholder, e.g. `%s`, and you are not passing any values that should replace the placeholders.

Comment: One fix (assuming PHP's `printf` is similar to C's) is to change `printf($output)` to `printf("%s", $output)`

Answer (score 3):

This could happen if $output contains one or more format specifiers. Can you use echo instead of printf?

Answer (score 3):

As written in the [first answer by James McLeod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515143/367456), maybe that helps you:

```
printf(str_tr($output, '%', '%%');
```

You need to escape `%` characters of `$output` first. That's done by adding another `%` in front of them. See as well the [`sprintf` manual page<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://de.php.net/sprintf) that explains the formatting codes, specifically this part:

> 6. A type specifier that says what type the argument data should be treated as. Possible types:
>
> - % - a literal percent character. No argument is required.

The important message here is that with `%%` instead of `%` no argument is required.

But that's merely for explanation, better is in you case:

```
print $output;
```

You do not need to do any formatted printing here, so use [`print`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://de.php.net/print) instead of `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $replyTemplate = '<div class="module_content">
                    <fieldset style="width:100%%; float:left;">
                        <table width="100%%" align="center" border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="15%%">
                                    <h3>%s</h3>
                                </td>
                                <td width="85%%">
                                    <h3>2015/06/11 09:06</h3>
                                    <h4>%s</h4>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset><div class="clear"></div>
                </div>';
```

and use sprintf instead printf.

Example from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776376/using-printf-to-format-html-too-few-arguments